# Error when popup is loaded 'Unchecked runtime.lastError'

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

So Basically I'm getting this error everytime the popup is opened, assuming its everytime sendMessage is sent. My Listener is in a content script that only loads on certain pages so could that be the reason? should have the listener in a background script instead?

#### Error Info:

Error: `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`

Context: `popup.html`

Stack Trace: `popup.html:0 (anonymous function)`

#### popup.html

```
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous">



    <style>
        .notif {
            visibility: hidden;
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: visibility 0s linear 0.5s, opacity 0.5s linear;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        .outer {
            position: relative;
            height: 80px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .notif.unhidden {
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
            transition-delay: 0.4s;
        }

        #copy {
            background-color: rgb(135, 135, 135);
            border-radius: 4px;
            border-width: 1px;
        }

        #text-copy {
            text-align: center;
            padding-left: 5px;
            padding-top: 5px;
            padding-left: 5px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            font-size: x-small;
            color: rgb(7, 7, 7);

        }

        .popup {
            padding-left: 20px;
            padding-right: 20px;
            padding-top: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="hero is-transparent" style="height: fit-content; background-color: #1e1e1e;">

        <div class="popup">

            <div class="outer">
                <div class="notif unhidden" id="n1"><img src="./assets/banners/top-banner-url.png"></div>
                <div class="notif notification is-danger" id="failCopynotif"><button class="delete"></button>Failed to
                    Copy to Clipboard</div>
                <div class="notif notification is-danger" id="errornotif"><button class="delete"></button>Error</div>
                <div class="notif notification is-success" id="copynotif"><button class="delete"></button>Copied to
                    Clipboard</div>
                <div class="notif notification is-success" id="startednotif"><button class="delete"></button>Started
                    Download</div>
            </div>

            <div style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                <button class="clipboard-btn button is-dark is-centered"
                    style="border-color: rgb(154, 154, 154); width: 100%;"><i class="fal fa-clipboard"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    Copy to Clipboard</button>
            </div>

            <div style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                <button class="download-btn button is-dark is-centered"
                    style="border-color: rgb(154, 154, 154); width: 100%;"><i
                        class="fal fa-arrow-alt-to-bottom"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; Download </button>
                <!-- is-loading -->
            </div>

            <div style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                <a><button class="support-btn button is-dark is-centered"
                        style="border-color: rgb(154, 154, 154); width: 100%;"><i
                            class="fal fa-book-heart"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; Support </button></a>
            </div>

            <div style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
                <a><button class="help-btn button is-danger is-centered"
                        style="border-color: rgb(37, 37, 37); width: 100%;"><i
                            class="fal fa-question-circle"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; Get Help / FAQ</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/popup.js"></script>

</body>
```

#### popup.js

```
var url = []
var data = []

function run() {

    url.length = 0

    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {

        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
            action: "get-links"
        }, function (response) {

            data.length = 0

            if (response === undefined) return console.log('Undefined')

            let respLinks = response.info.links.join(', ').replace(/"/g, '')

            data.push(respLinks)

            return;

        });
    });
}

function copy() {
    chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
    }, function (tabs) {

        let started = document.querySelector('#copynotif')
        let banner = document.querySelector('#n1')
        banner.classList.remove('unhidden')
        started.classList.add('unhidden')

        setTimeout(function () {

            started.classList.remove('unhidden')
            banner.classList.add('unhidden')

        }, 4000);


        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
            action: "copy"
        })


    });
}

function dl() {
    chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
    }, async function (tabs) {

        let started = document.querySelector('#startednotif')
        let banner = document.querySelector('#n1')
        banner.classList.remove('unhidden')
        started.classList.add('unhidden')

        setTimeout(function () {

            started.classList.remove('unhidden')
            banner.classList.add('unhidden')
        }, 4000);


        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
            action: "download"
        })


    });
}

run()

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    (document.querySelectorAll('.notification .delete') || []).forEach(($delete) => {
        const $notification = $delete.parentNode;

        $delete.addEventListener('click', () => {
            $notification.parentNode.removeChild($notification);

            let banner = document.querySelector('#n1')
            banner.classList.add('unhidden')

        });
    });

    var down = document.querySelectorAll('.download-btn')
    var clip = document.querySelectorAll('.clipboard-btn')

    down[0].addEventListener('click', (dl));
    clip[0].addEventListener('click', (copy));
});
```

Comment: It means the content script isn't running, e.g. if you reloaded the extension but didn't reload the tab. The usual solution is to switch to executeScript, [example](/q/4532236).

Comment: Cheers @wOxxOm, can you link me an example? the only thing i can find is the docs or something to do with injecting css or smthn.

Comment: I've linked an example in my comment.